# Function for pop up message in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, sqlite

I have HTML file. What ever the details user has entered before submitting I want user to get a pop up message where users will be able to view all the details which he/she has entered in the form. I would like to know what function to be used so that before submitting the form a pop message comes for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care much about layout of this pop-Up, just use `window.confirm()`

You can build this into your HTML form like this:

```
<html>
  <script>
    function checkForm() {
      var message = "You entered following data:\n" + 
        "Car name: " + document.getElementById('cn').value + "\n" +
        "Car color: " + document.getElementById('cc').value + "\n" + 
        "Is this correct?";
      if (window.confirm(message))
        document.getElementById("carform").submit();
    }

  </script>


  <form id="carform" target="...">
    Car name: <input type="text" name="carname" id="cn"/><br/>
    Car color: <input type="text" name="carcolor" id="cc"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="checkForm()"/>
  </form>

</html>
```

**EDIT**
To compare the entered values to the ones you have stored in your SQL database, you have to use PHP. You could realize it for example like this:

```
<html>
  <script>
    function checkForm() {
      <?php
        //Query the current databse values and store them for example in $carcolor $carname
        echo 'var currentCarName = "' . $carname . '"';
        echo 'var currentCarColor = "' . $carcolor . '"';

      ?>
      var message = "You entered following data:\n" + 
        "Car name: "    + document.getElementById('cn').value + "\n" +
        "  Old name: "  + currentCarName + "\n" +
        "Car color: "   + document.getElementById('cc').value + "\n" + 
        "  Old color: " + currentCarColor + "\n" +
        "Is this correct?";
      if (window.confirm(message))
        document.getElementById("carform").submit();
    }

  </script>


  <form id="carform" target="...">
    Car name: <input type="text" name="carname" id="cn"/><br/>
    Car color: <input type="text" name="carcolor" id="cc"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="checkForm()"/>
  </form>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I fetch car name or Car color from the database?? I have sql query to fetch car name or car color. How to Display the car name or car color in the pop up message or HTML.

Comment: As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/857670/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-javascript#answer-857688 you shouldn't use JavaScript to access your Database since everyone will see the database credentials in the HTML-Code. But the linked answer describes, how to do it anyway.

The clean approach would be doing this in PHP.

Comment: Am Connecting  Database from PHP itself. Am retrieving few fields and I want to display it for the  user with the help of pop up message.

Comment: I edited my answer to give you an example, how this could look like, using PHP.

Comment: I got the soln for my problem. Sample code was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: ISoleyl is there any other method other than using popup message. For eg it connects to another HTML file and displays all the fields.

Comment: If you mean that you want to display the entered values in the HTML page, which you see after you press "submit", then yes it is possible. You have to change the form to: `<form action="yournextpage.php" method="POST">`

Then you can access the values in the phpfile, using `$_POST['varname']` where  `varname` is the name of the input field. If you just wish to display the dialog better, you should have a look at these dialogs: [JQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). In these dialogs you can display every valid HTML-element.

Comment: That worked. While I was trying to find answer I found one more answer where I can display within the page need not go to the next page by using the method hide and show.http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp.

Comment: Problem with this  method is from database the value which I have echo backed not able to display.

Comment: I pasted a sample code on Pastebin. If your code looks similar to this, it should work: http://pastebin.com/Gn5YcUFL

Comment: have pasted my code can you help me out http://pastebin.com/QyjGh8jC

Comment: Okay, 3 things which might cause problems on your side. 1) since I don't have the headers, which you include, I don't know whether you include JQuery correctly (for reference see my pastebin post). 2) You are sending a POST request to manage.php and passing your arguments in the URL (which is typical for the GET method). I don't know how this manage.php works, but I emulated the ajax-call by setting the result to `var res="10000:John:Jay:Rambo"` 3) The text in the tables doesn't change, because `val()` is only for input fields. You have to use `html()`. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native function for making a pop up message show up loading HTML.
However there is FancyBox which does exactly this.

http://fancybox.net/

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963338/loading-inline-content-using-fancybox) and [this blog](http://fancybox.net/blog) for more information on how to do this